# Cannot retrieve QueryParams Angular 14

Tags: angular

I have a newly created Angular 14 application.
I've created a simple component called TestComponent.

Inside the routing.module.ts I've specified the following Route:

`const routes: Routes = [{ path:'test', component: TestComponent }]`

The problem occurs when I try to navigate to this component passing some query params like this:

http://mysite:80/test?param=teststring

The component is loaded without problems, but no query params is retrieved.
It's the same situation if typed http://mysite:80/test

As far as I understand from the documentation, this url should be valid and by accessing params with

```
this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
       let myparam = params.get('param');
    });
```

this.route is an ActivatedRoute object, injected inside the constructor of the component

I should be able to get the value, but I keep getting null.
Since it's a query parameter, it's optional and so the route specified inside the routing.module.ts should be correct.

Any idea on how I can solve it?

Comment: try `path: ':test'` (the additional colon character)

Comment: There is not enough code here. What is this.route? Where are you trying to get the queryParam?

Answer (score 1):

The query parameters are initially empty or does not load the values first because the components loads before the actual routing is applied.

**Solution 1**

Wait for the navigation to end using event property NavigationEnd

```js
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router:Router) { }
ngOnInit(): void {  
    this.router.events.subscribe(
      (event: RouterEvent) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => { //You may also use simply route.params as well instead of queryParamMap
                    let myparam = params.get('param');
          });
      }
   })
}
```

**Solution 2**

Another approach could be adding a delay,say .10s to the subscription. Try avoiding this approach unless and until you have a pre requirement of some kind of delay on pageload.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => { 
                    let myparam = params.get('param');
          });
    }, 10);   // A delay of 10ms is provided here
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax here, using `:test` in your case: https://angular-training-guide.rangle.io/routing/routeparams
example:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'product-list', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'product-list', component: ProductList },
 { path: 'product-details/:id', component: ProductDetails }
];


URL: localhost:3000/product-details/5
```

Comment: This is the syntax for passing route params. 
I'm trying to retrieve a query param.
I've no control on it because the url I've posted above is generated by an external server which ships the redirect url with a query param

Comment: but have you tried `path: ':test'` in your routing.module ?

Comment: @bob.mazzo that's for defining a required parameter, not a query parameter. You can read about the different types of parameters here:  https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-route-parameters-a-simple-guide-88c69d54102c

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you want to subscribe to the observable?

If all you need is to read the query parameters on component initialization, then try this instead:
`this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('param')`